# Django - properly call a child template

Tags: jquery, python, django, django-templates, django-views

**I have a simple question in `Django`:**

It is possible to call a child template without loading the whole page? Because basically if you call the child template with `{% extends %}` it changes the url and load the whole page.

I use the `jquery` approach to call another template in my application **not using template inheritance**.

```
$('#bvc-workplace').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();

       document.title = "Project Name - Workplace";
       var url = $(this).attr("href");
       $('.app-content').load(url);
 });
```

**This is my base.html as simplified**

```
.... styles ....
.... scripts ...

<ul>
    <li>
       <a id="bvc-workplace" href="{% url 'project:workplace' %}">
       <i class="fa fa-building fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       <span>Workplace</span>
       </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="app-content">

</div>
```

**This is my workplace.html**

```
<div>
     This is the workplace index page!
</div>
```

Hope i explained it well.

Comment: I don't see any Django template inheritance related tags in your code. So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: My question is related to `template inheritance` the code actually represent my approach without using `template inheritance`. That is what ive done so far. calling templates via jquery `load()`

Comment: Then, it is not a Django question.

Comment: why sir? i ask the possibility of calling a child template in django without loading the whole page and i presented my approach without using inheritance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for.  Do you want to reload the current page with different content and keep the same URL?

Comment: i would like to call the child template inside an element such as a div of a base.html without loading the whole page using template inheritance sir. because i cannot achieve doing so because calling a child template would reload the whole page.

Comment: I don't understand what it means to "call a template".  Templates are not executable.  It sounds like you want to take some element on the current page and dynamically replace its content with different content, without reloading the page?

Comment: yes sir that is what i mean, it is impossible with template inheritance? i am new to Django so i am not familiar with the term well.

Comment: Templates and views are different things. You seem to be confusing them. Templates has nothing to do with URLs, for starters.

Comment: yes and views are something like controllers that 'what template should be presented', thanks for pointing out

Comment: Do you know beforehand that you want to display the child template, or is this decision made on the fly?  If you know beforehand, you can use `{% include child_template.html %}` in the parent template.

Comment: it is something like you are importing another template to the parent template. you can use that dynamically? i never thought that way